# Popup issue after upgrading jQuery from 1.11.1 to 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I was using jQuery 1.11.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.5, everything is working fine. Recently I have upgraded jQuery to 3.3.1. I am getting popup issue. I am getting below error when i tried to open the popup in button onlick by calling popupCaptureOptions() function.

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
    at w.Event.preventDefault (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.Event.preventDefault (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:7
    at i (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

My html page looks like below.

```
 <div data-role="page" id="previewscreen">
        <main>
            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                <div id="ID_IMAGE_DIV" class="ID_IMAGE_DIV">
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <div data-role="popup" data-history="false" data-overlay-theme="a" data-position-to="window" id="imagePopup">
            <a class="popup_refrence" href="#" data-rel="back"></a>
            <img id="popupImage" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="popup" data-dismissible="false" data-position-to="window" class="ui-content" id="ID_EXTRACTIONERRORPOPUP">
            <a href="#" id="cancel" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
            <p class='error'>Extraction Failed.</p>
            <div id="ID_MORETEXT"></div>
            <a id="ID_MORE" href="#">Read more</a>
            <p id="extractionfailed"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="capture_popupalert" data-dismissible="false" data-position-to="window" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="b">
            <h4 style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px">Capture Options</h4>
            <hr style=" margin-top: 0;" />
            <div id="back_capture" style="margin-top:5%">
                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <a style="background-color:#00b3b3;color:white;margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px;" id="back_capture_button" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Capture Back</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="skip" style="margin-top:5%">
                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <a style="background-color:#00b3b3;color:white;margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px;" id="skip_button" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Skip</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My javascript code is

```
var popupCaptureOptions = function() {
        var imgFrontElement = document.getElementById("ID_IMAGE_DIV");
        var content_width = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible").outerWidth();
        $('#capture_popupalert').css({'width':content_width*0.8});
        $("#capture_popupalert").popup("open");
        $("#back_capture").click(function() {
            capturedSide = CAPTURESIDE.CAPTURE_BACK;
            doCapture();
        });

        $("#skip").click(function() {
            $("#capture_popupalert").hide();
            imgFrontElement.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            Utils.showLoadingIndicator();
            if (currentModule == Module.MOBILEID) {
                MobileIDModule.extractData(frontCapturedImage, backCapturedImage, isOnBoardingFlow, region);
            } else if (currentModule == Module.CHECK) {
                CheckDepositModule.extractData(frontCapturedImage, backCapturedImage, isOnBoardingFlow, region);
            }
            frontCapturedImage = null;
        });
    };
```

Please help me how can solve this issue.

Comment: provide your javascript code in the question

Comment: You made **two** major upgrade bumps. Has any of your code changed? jQuery did introduce a lot of breaking changes from 1->2 and I am sure they did the same from 2->3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple.

jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 was not made to work with the latest jQuery versions.

These are supported jQuery versions for jQM 1.4.5: jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1

More about them can be found [here](https://jquerymobile.com/).

So either upgrade to jQM 1.5 or use an older version of jQuery.

Comment: This fixed the same problem for me. I was running jQuery 2.2.4. Downgraded for mobile to 2.1.4 and now the problem is gone. Where is jQuery Mobile 1.5?

Comment: 3 years and jQuery Mobile and 1.5 is still not out and latest still doesn't work with the latest jQuery... It's time to move to Bootstrap...

Answer (score 1):

*jQuery Mobile 1.5.0 release-candidate-1* works fine with the newer versions of jQuery. I'm working with jQuery 3.2.1, and upgrading the JQM version to 1.5.0-rc1 fixed the popup issue I was experiencing using JQM version 1.4.5.

You can find the newer JQM version [here](https://code.jquery.com/mobile/), or alternatively use the following links:

- [jQuery.mobile.1.5.0-rc1.js](https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.js) (uncompressed)
- [jQuery.mobile.1.5.0-rc1.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.js) (minified)
- [jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.css](https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.css) (theme)

According to [JQM's upgrade guide](https://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.5/),

> 1.5 maintains full compatibility with the 1.4 API by default. This is accomplished by rebuilding the 1.4 API on top of the 1.5 API.

implying that you'll probably be running into minimal backwards compatibility issues.